# How to supress -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast and -Werror=address kind of errors in Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gnu

How to supress `-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast` and `-Werror=address` kind of errors in Linux?

I know below are options to use for suppressing the above errors.

```
-Wno-error=address
-Wno-pointer-to-int-cast
```

But my question is how to use them or where to edit the compiler settings as I am building a large project.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If yes, which one?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the errors, rather than ignore them? (Unless you know what you're doing and have a really good reason.)

Comment: You need to tell us how you're calling the compiler: from IDE, makefile etc

Answer (score 3):

Put them in CFLAGS if you are using a standard Makefile build system.

If it's an autoconf project, put it in Makefile.am like this:

CFLAGS = -Wno-error=address -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast

If you're using some other build system, it needs to be passed to gcc command line when compiling .c files to .o.

If it's an existing package that uses autoconf, you can pass it to ./configure like this:

$ ./configure --extra-cflags='-Wno-error=address -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast'

Other autoconf based projects take it from the environment instead of (or in addition to) --extra-cflags:

$ CFLAGS='-Wno-error=address -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast' ./configure --any-other-options-you-need

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gcc, consider the following :

1. You can simply compile your program using :
   gcc -o obj src_file

   src_file : *.c ( any file name with ".c" extension )
2. If you are using Makefiles, then

   #SRC stands for source file
   #OBJ stands for object file
   SRC = file.c
   OBJ = file
   CFLAGS = -Wall # do not include the -Werror flag, otherwise warnings will be
                   # treated as errors.
   $(OBJ) : $(SRC)
         gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJ) $(SRC)